# What type of energy comes off powerlines that can be photographed or seen

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electrostatics

[image]Like in my photo of powerlines ..what's one to call that??[image]

Comment: This question, with similar photos, has been asked here before a couple of times.  I don't know if the earlier posts are by the same person.   I don't think an answer has emerged.  Until more information comes from the OP, we have no choice but to ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually no visible energy comes from power lines, because the electricity in them alternates at a frequency of 50 Hz or 60 Hz, which is much too small to create visible light waves.

Comment: Then what is it in my photograph. . That's a pic of powerlines and what electrical flux?

Comment: I really don't know what that is, perhaps you could supply some more information about how you made the photograph and someone might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: It's a picture of powerlines I took ..it's the enegry being lost off the powerlines..and i guess im the only 1 who figured out how to take pics of this . I got dozens of these..

Comment: We can talk more if youd like ..Google hangouts rummyjer

Comment: Well this is science not guessing. If you don't tell how you got the photograph, there is no way to answer the question.

Comment: I took a photo of the powerlines.. the rest is a secret for now since nobody can tell me what it is..I think Its gaussian state of electrical flux or point of discharge. .

Comment: @Rummyjer: *"the rest is a secret for now since nobody can tell me what it is"* Suzu is right, of course. We can't know what it is unless we know how it was photographed. They look more like an 'artist's rendition' than a photo to me (scepticism is part of science, so don't take that personal!)

Comment: Check out my youtube channel. I got dozens of them pics .https://youtu.be/cmQvVPO70ZA